# Part time yeshiva in New York

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, yeshiva-school, semicha, college-university-school

Are there any yeshivas in New York wich I could go and get a semicha while going to university?

Comment: YU? Or you have a specific college you want to go to

Comment: Are you looking for a yeshiva that has a built in college program? Or do you want to go to a regular college and go to said yeshiva as well?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71505/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-part-time-yeshiva-in-new-york).

Comment: You dont mention your present knowledge of talmud. You have to realize you cant just start off with semicha. Unless you are capable of managing to learn a blatt gemoro with rashi and tosfos and meforshim on your own, then you are not yet ready to take a semicha course. Using a short cut like the kitsur wont get you there.

Answer (score 5):

You can maintain such an academic schedule while learning in a *semicha* program (rabbinic ordination) at*:

1. Yeshiva University; Rabbi Isaac Elchanan Theological Seminary (RIETS)
2. Kollel L'Horaah Ohr Reuven
3. Yeshiva Torah Vodaath

---

- Among others which I'll add as I recall

Comment: However, such maintenance may prove quite difficult depending on how flexibly you can design your academic schedule and how many years you want this whole process to take.

Comment: Is Yeshiva University; Rabbi Isaac Elchanan Theological Seminary (RIETS) geared only for a certian "type" or are there many types of groups there?

Comment: @AviM Diversely geared. (Source: personal experience.)

Comment: @Oliver How can I contact u?

Comment: @AviM I’m afraid you can’t. But, feel free to ask/comment about relevant info. concerning OP’s question (or post independently) and hopefully I can provide you with info. you seek.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out [Ohr Yisroel](http://www.ohryisroel.org) in Brooklyn. You can get Semicha and an MBA under one roof.